# Reconnecting USB drive

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-storage

I have a Lenovo ThinkCenter M900 running Win10 Pro, all has been working well until recently.  When I boot I can connect to an external USB drive.  When I disconnect the drive there a an error in the device manager about

> The driver could not be loaded because a previous version of the
> driver is still in memory.

I removed the USB Device in the Device Manager and rebooted.  I thought it may be related to a recent update from Microsoft, so I backed out the updates.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you safely remove devices.  Try a different device to check.

Comment: Yes I eject the drive successfully.  I power off the drive, and re-power the drive and it doesn't connect.  I also can not connect any other drive once I disconnect a drive, unless I reboot.

Comment: Use Lenovo Update App to update all drivers.  Then update USB connections using Device Manager. Expand the USB section, right click on each item and select Update.  Then when complete all the above, do a final restart and test.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I find Windows *Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media* fails to perform correctly. For example, when trying to eject a SDXC card from a particular reader, only the *card* is ejected. If another card is inserted, it does not show.

There are some free, third-party tools that I find more reliable, such as [Hot Swap](http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm) and [USB Safely Remove](https://safelyremove.com/index.htm). With *Hot Swap*, for example, I'm able to remove and successfully reinsert either card or reader. Perhaps one of those tools will fix that issue of failing to reload an external USB drive.

Comment: I used the Lenovo update app. and I installed additional drivers inside of Windows.  This didn't have any affect.  Next I deleted some USB devices from withing the Device Manager, and rebooted.  This made things worse.  I can only connect to a UDB HDD if it is plugged when the system boots.  When I plug a drive in I see this message in the Device Manager

Comment: Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware because
a previous instance of the device driver is still in memory. (Code 38)

The driver could not be loaded because a previous version of the
driver is still in memory.